# window.open in new window/tab from iframe won't work in safari on osx

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari, window.open

I've created an iframe module/widget thing that lets whoever who have access to their own html code put this thing on their site.

And everything seems to work in: Opera, Firefox and Chrome. But not Safari (on OSX).
*Also IE and Firefox on windows 7 is tested and works well...*

The iframe module/widget is a chained-select where the last selection should open a new window/tab immediately when selected.
To prevent opening the destination site inside the iframe, I've used `window.open('url','_blank')` to force-open it in a new window/tab.

Here's the code for this particular action:

```
var sel4th = 'select#ap_engine';

$(sel4th).change(function(){
    window.open('https://www.autopower.no?Page=Tuning&view=vehicle&type='+$(sel1st+' option:selected').attr('id')+'&id='+$(sel4th+' option:selected').val(),'_blank');
});
```

This code, as I mention at the beginning, seems to work great in most browsers but Safari (on OSX).

I've tried replacing `window.open()` with `location.href='';` with positive results; Except that the website then opens inside of the iframe...

I've placed a working demo here at http://dev.thomaskile.me/?page=test-zone&module=Autopower-Iframe for you to see what I'm crying about...